# WPF Element layout

Tags: wpf

Running into a problem with my WPF layout on client machines

Running from client machine

[image: All collapsed]
[image: Call Info collapsed]
[image: None collapsed]

Here it is running on my dev machine
[image: How it should look]

Here is by windows layout

```
<dx:DXWindow
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
    xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
    xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
    xmlns:lc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/layoutcontrol"
    x:Class="CallID.MainWindow"
    Title="Interaction Call ID Log Search" Height="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}" Width="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="True"
    dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="HybridApp" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Icon="search.ico">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="3" MaxHeight="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0*" MinHeight="3" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Padding="6,6,3,6" Height="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="DATE SELECTION" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5 5 5 5" FontWeight="Bold" />
                <dxe:DateEdit x:Name="deLogDate" Margin="5 5 5 5" FontWeight="Bold" Mask="yyyy-MM-dd" ShowClearButton="False" IsTextEditable="False" Validate="deLogDate_Validate" MaskType="Numeric" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" EditValueChanged="deLogDate_EditValueChanged" />
                <TextBlock Text="LOG PATH" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5 5 5 5" FontWeight="Bold" />
                <dxe:TextEdit x:Name="tbLogPath" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="5 5 5 5" FontWeight="Bold" CharacterCasing="Normal" />
                <TextBlock Text="INTERACTION ID" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5 5 5 5" FontWeight="Bold" />
                <dxe:TextEdit x:Name="tbInteractionID" Margin="5 5 5 5" FontWeight="Bold"  MaskType="Numeric" Mask="##########" Validate="tbInteractionID_Validate" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False" LostFocus="tbInteractionID_LostFocus" />
                <lc:GroupBox Header="QUICK LOG FILTERING" Margin="5 5 5 5" MinimizeElementVisibility="Visible" FontWeight="Bold" State="Normal">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button x:Name="btnAllLogs" FontWeight="Bold" Content="ALL" Margin="5 5 5 5" Click="btnAllLogs_Click" />
                        <Button x:Name="btnBigFourLogs" FontWeight="Bold" Content="BIG FOUR" Margin="5 5 5 5" Click="btnBigFourLogs_Click" />
                        <Button x:Name="btnSwitchoverLogs" FontWeight="Bold" Content="SWITCHOVER" Margin="5 5 5 5" Click="btnSwitchoverLogs_Click" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </lc:GroupBox>
                <lc:GroupBox Header="CALL INFO" Margin="5 5 5 5" MinimizeElementVisibility="Visible" FontWeight="Bold">
                    <ScrollViewer MinHeight="142" MaxHeight="142" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="tbCallInfo" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </lc:GroupBox>
                <Button x:Name="btnSearchLogs" Content="SEARCH" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5 5 5 5" Click="btnSearchLogs_Click" IsEnabled="False" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" Padding="3,6,6,3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <dxg:GridControl x:Name="gridLogControl" DataContext="{Binding InteractionLogs}" Margin="5 5 5 5">
                <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="LOG NAME" ReadOnly="True" AllowSorting="True" AllowBestFit="True" HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center" Binding="{Binding}" />
                </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                <dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>
                    <dxg:GridSummaryItem FieldName="LOG NAME" SummaryType="Count" DisplayFormat="LOGS: {0}" />
                </dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>
                <dxg:GridControl.View>
                    <dxg:TableView ShowTotalSummary="True" AutoWidth="True" AllowBestFit="True" BestFitMode="Smart" x:Name="viewLogView" FontWeight="Bold" ShowGroupPanel="False" ShowFilterPanelMode="Never" AllowPerPixelScrolling="True" />
                </dxg:GridControl.View>
            </dxg:GridControl>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Padding="3,3,6,6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Grid>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</dx:DXWindow>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong as it will not fit to the layout on the client machines. Any ideas?

Noticeable difference between machines

Dev Box:

Physical Machine
Screen Resolution: 1920x1080
OS: Win 8.1 x64

Client Machine
RDP Session
Screen Resolution: 1844x534
OS: Win Server 2k8 R2

Comment: can you make it a bit more obvious what exactly is different between machines? I can't tell the difference

Comment: What is the problem? The only thing I see is that the client machines are smaller than your dev machine.

Comment: Added the info and yes the client machine display less, I need to resolve it so it looks the same on both

Comment: what happens when you set the window size to a fixed height/width?  are the client machines having same resolution/monitor size?

Comment: So, basically you just need a scroll view? Your content on the left is too large to fit in the 534 height, right?

Comment: yeah that could probably work